# Check user existence using GitHub API

Tags: python, api, github, user-input, github-api

I am using GitHub API with python. I want to validate the user existence.

`url = f"https://api.github.com/users/{username}"`

`r = requests.get(url.format(username)).json()`

I want to know that, what do GitHub API returns when the 'username' doesn't exists. 
I know it returns an error message of not found, but what do it returns as python?
What can I do to validate it?

Answer (score 2):

It returns a JSON object with an error message as follows:

```
{
  "message": "Not Found",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3/users/#get-a-single-user"
}
```

You can look for the "message" key with a "Not Found" value in your response `r` to check if the user does not exist.

In short:

```
url = f"https://api.github.com/users/{username}"
r = requests.get(url.format(username)).json()
if "message" in r:
    if r["message"] == "Not Found":   # Just to be double sure
        print ("User does not exist.")
```

Edit: In case you're curious, I just tried with a bunch of random usernames, and soon found one that did not exist. That's how I found this response. Try with `https://api.github.com/users/llllaaa`

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution, not relying on the response body, but simply checking the response **status code**.

A user is a resource in REST semantics.

If the user doesn't exist then we expect response status code `404` - Not Found.

Documented here on the [Github API Docs - Get a user](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/users#get-a-user)

**Demo:**

```
>>> import requests

>>> r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/users/vineetvdubey')
>>> r.status_code
200

>>> r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/users/non-existing-user__')
>>> r.status_code
404
```

Answer (score 1):

In python what you get is a map .

look for r['login'] if this value doesn't exits , which means the user_name you provided is a valid one. so you can throw some try catch like this.

```py
import requests

def checkUser(user):
    url = f"https://api.github.com/users/{user}"
    r = requests.get(url.format(user)).json()
    try:
        return r['login']
    except:
        return 'No User'


print(checkUser('raja-ravi-prakash'))
```

Comment: That's a fair solution. The only issue is that there could be a number of things that can go wrong in the `try` block. In that case, the program will output `'No User'` irrespective of whatever raised an exception. Something like a broken internet connection will also return `'No User'`. Not really ideal! :)

Comment: may be i should exclude url line ad r line outside of try catch

Answer (score 1):

So, I am answering my own question.

The method which worked best for me, and will work best in every situation is by **calculating and validating it through the length of the dictionary it returns**.

`length = len(r)`

If 'length' is equal to 2, username doesn't exist. 
else:
     username exist.

Because, the error message returned by the API, when username isn't found is in the form of:

```
{
  "message": "Not Found",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3/users/#get-a-single-user"
}
```

as mentioned by @PrateekDewan in the above/below answer.

So, calculating and validating it using the length of the returned dictionary/map can be a short and simple solution.